# fixed menu inside scroll incorrectly

Tags: ios, css, menu, static

I'm working on a website where the client would like the menu to be static at the top of the page, and when the menu is opened it opens a static menu which can be scrolled in case there are more menus than on the screen.

I have this working correctly expect apparently on iphone 6 (not sure if other iphones are affected) when a user first scrolls the menu goes the opposite direction of the scroll. After first touch, it works fine.

http://readysalteddev.co.uk/hotrod/

CSS

```
.menu-primary-menu-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: $header-scrolled-height 0 auto;
    z-index: 99999;
    display: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
}
```

I read somewhere while researching that `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` might have helped, but apparently it hasn't.

I'm working blind as I only have an ipad and android for testing, and it seemingly works perfect on both of these, including every web browser (not IE of course)

**UPDATE**

Just saw on another question that maybe adding

```
     -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform:translateZ(0);
    -o-transform:translateZ(0);
    transform:translateZ(0);
```

Might help. Uploaded it and waiting on tester to confirm what happens.

**UPDATE AGAIN**

Didn't help apparently.

Answer (score 0):

i see some problems when the menu is opened (i can still scroll the page)

maybe you disable scroll all together when the menu is opened

you can do this adding `overflow: hidden` & `height: 100%;` on HTML

what OS does that Iphone have? older version have problems with `position: fixed`

EDIT after inspecting your code

1. there are a lot of containers floated in mobile breakpoint . maybe you remove those floats
2. `html` & `body` receive `overflow: hidden` & `height: 100%;`
3. `#site-navigation .menu-primary-menu-container` gets `fixed height` & `overflow: auto`

   - the fixed height should be 100% so it takes the entire screen (or 450px if u dont care that much) . but adding 100% wont do the trick . because that container is inside a bunch of other containers (some of them) with fixed height and overflow hidden (not auto) . so if u want to achieve 100% on the menu . then #header is the place to start . make its 100% height (only on menu opened state) and go down the line until you reach the menu .. or get the entire menu of #header

hope it helps . gl

Comment: Sadly the client is looking to make it so you can still scroll the menu, so disabling the behaviour is out of the question.

I'm told the OS is the latest update. 

I saw reference to issues with `position: fixed` but more that it is completely ignored. This seems not to do that, just on first touch on the menu it scrolls downwards, rather than up to see the rest of the menu items.

Comment: the menu yes . the page no . overflow auto on menu . overflow hidden on page

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll give it a go but unfortunately my tester is not available until Monday now. I'll try it then and I'll get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mihnea I've tried this and although the effect works on desktop and android it doesn't seem to have had an effect on ios devices, tested on iPhone 6 and iPad 1 (both on the newest ios). If you can try this for me to confirm along with any other suggestions I would be grateful?